# setting of TFS on Linux CentOS (on Azure IaaS VM)

Tags: tfs, centos

Currently i am using git and this application(Perl,Apache on linux CentOS) is on-premise. This same application needs to be migrated to Azure VM(IaaS) and Git needs to be replaced by TFS. Please help.

Comment: You need to elaborate your query, so that we can help.

Comment: Do you mean to say git needs to be hosted on TFS or do you mean git needs to be replaced with TFSVC?

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to check TFS [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements). If you want to set up on-premise TFS, the requirements need to be met (TFS doesn't support Linux system).

Then, you can check [Run Team Foundation Server (TFS) on Azure Virtual Machines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn769056.aspx) and download the guide, which provides practical, scenario-based guidance for the implementation of Team Foundation Server (TFS) on Azure Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS).

Comment: Currently i have a git and this application(Perl on linux CentOS) is on-premise. This same application needs to be migrated to Azure VM and Git needs to be replaced by TFS.Please help.

Comment: OP never asked about hosting TFS on Linux or on Azure

Comment: @AbhaySaraf OP has modified his question.

Comment: @Test Are you going to use on-premise TFS or Visual Studio Team Service? Both of them support Git version control. You can get start with Git by following tutorial: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart